# How to insert a Twitter bounce animation to tab bar

Tags: swift, xcode, class, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class AnimatedTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    private var bounceAnimation: CAKeyframeAnimation = {
        let bounceAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        bounceAnimation.values = [1.0, 1.4, 0.9, 1.02, 1.0]
        bounceAnimation.duration = TimeInterval(0.3)
        bounceAnimation.calculationMode = CAAnimationCalculationMode.cubic
        return bounceAnimation
    }()

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        // find index if the selected tab bar item, then find the corresponding view and get its image, the view position is offset by 1 because the first item is the background (at least in this case)
        guard let idx = tabBar.items?.firstIndex(of: item), tabBar.subviews.count > idx + 1, let imageView = tabBar.subviews[idx + 1].subviews.first as? UIImageView else {
            return
        }

        imageView.layer.add(bounceAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }

}
```

I am trying to create the twitter bounce animation when you click on an icon although this code is not doing anything. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this out? I am stuck in the same spot you are in the code snippet. I cannot seam to get the images to bounce.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set the class for my tab bar controller